# Why is Docker OS image size so small?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

If I pull a Ubuntu image from Docker Hub using `docker pull ubuntu:14.04` and then list my images with `docker images` I see that the Ubuntu image has a virtual size of just ~188MB. I don't understand why the image size is so much smaller than the size of an Ubuntu ISO that I might use to run a VM on OS X. I use OS X, so I use docker-machine to set up a docker daemon. How is Docker able to run an Ubuntu image on OS X with such a small footprint?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because docker images usually contain only the bare minimum. In case of an Ubuntu image, it contains only the base system without GUI (which is rarely used in containers) and without most tools. Ubuntu's docker image is actually relatively big; there are much smaller ones.

Comment: and Debian is between 84 and 122 MB, depending upon the versions

Comment: For a truly tiny image, check out [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) at around 20 MB.

Comment: It's still a huge difference. So you're saying the GUI and the tools account for 80+% of the size of an Ubuntu ISO?

Comment: @mblakesley yes, in old times when internet was slow and expensive minimal images were much more popular, they still exists, but not many people using them nowadays, for ubuntu you can see sizes here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD